# Does a static_map costmap continually update from map_server?

Tags: navigation, mapping, costmap, static-map, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a basic conceptual question regarding Costmap2D. When using a global costmap with the static_map parameter true, I know that it will initialize the map with whatever is stored in map_server.

My question is, does this only happen once, when initializing the costmap, or will the costmap be periodically updated when the map in map_server changes?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107281/does-a-static_map-costmap-continually-update-from-map_server?/) by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on ROS Answers with karma: 504 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it continually updates, although I've experienced problems in some circumstances (not sure exactly which, it was a while ago).

---

Originally posted by [Siegfried Gevatter](https://answers.ros.org/users/1599/siegfried-gevatter/) with karma: 119 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0